# Codeigniter pagination with my own query

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

first be gentle im a begginer.

I have a problem with codeogniter pagination and im totally clules.

I watched a lot of tuts on the net and never got any aswer.

My problem is, im building a real-estate site, it has 2 types of estate, for sale and for rent.

My query looks like this

```
function for_sale()
{
    $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT city, rand_id, price, image FROM estate WHERE type = 'for_sale' ");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
       {
       foreach ($query->result() as $f)
         {
            $for_sale[] = $f;
        }
        return $for_sale;
        }
    }
```

my controller

```
function index()
            {
                $this->load->view("header");
                $this->load->model('estate_model');
                $for_sale['result'] = $this->estate_model->for_sale();
                $this->load->library('pagination');
                $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/kpi/for_sale/index';
                $config['total_rows'] = 22;
                $config['per_page'] = 9; 
                $config['num_links'] = 19; 

                $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

            //  $data['records'] = $this->db->get('ingatlan', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3)); 

                $this->load->view("for_sale_view",  $for_sale);
                $this->load->view("footer");
            }
```

and my view

```
foreach($results as $r) {
        echo '<div class="grid_4">';
            echo '<p class="title">Estate for sale</p>';
            echo '<div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="info">
                <p class="bar">'.$r->city.'</p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <a href="#">'.$r->image.'</a></div>';
            echo '<div class="more"><a href="#">View details</a></div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

So my problem is i cant figure this out how to use it with my query, i watched lots of tuts, that i need to load in the table library, and pass a data array like this

```
$data['records'] = $this->db->get('estate', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
```

anf give the per page this result `$this->db->get('estate')->num_rows(); but i would like this with my query, and not with a table.

So can someone hive me a hint?

Thank you

Comment: you can build your function that contains your query in controller and call that function from controller to get result from your query.

Comment: You have to be careful when dealing with index(). It gets called when either you call the controller with no second parameter or if you explicitly define it (my_controller/index). Have you tried setting the pagination base url like, $base_url = base_url().'for_sale/index/'; (I assume you base url is http://localhost/kpi/) and setting the uri_segment to be 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... i need to load in the table library, and pass a data array ...

how you display your data is totally up to you. the html-table *class* can help you with that, but it is not necessary to use it. your view should work just fine except for the fact that you want to iterate over `$results` which will be empty because you put your data into `$for_sale['result']` (results != result).

in order for the pagination library to work with your query, you have to pass your query 2 parameters:

1. how many rows/records should be loaded from your db (= `$config['per_page']`)
2. how many rows/records should be skipped at the beginning (also known as 'offset', this value will be provided by the pagination library = `$this->uri->segment(3)`)

So instead of:

```
$for_sale['result'] = $this->estate_model->for_sale();

Model:

function for_sale()
{
    $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT city, rand_id, price, image FROM estate WHERE type = 'for_sale' ");
    ...
}
```

you should try:

```
$for_sale['result'] = $this->estate_model->for_sale($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

Model:

function for_sale($per_page, $offset) {
   $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT city, rand_id, price, image FROM estate WHERE type = 'for_sale' LIMIT $offset, $per_page");
   ...
   return $query->result();
}
```

One last thing: the pagination library has to be initialized BEFORE you query the database.

And another last thing: `$config['total_rows'] = 22;` you will probably want to replace that with something like `$this->estate_model->get_for_sale_total_rows()`

Hope this helps.